# How do I see active cloud-config on CoreOS running on GCE?

Tags: google-compute-engine, coreos, cloud-config

I've got CoreOS beta 991.1.0 running on Google Compute Engine, and cloud-config is applied via the GCE instance's `user_data` metadata variable. How can I print the currently active cloud-config (for debugging purposes)?

Answer (score 1):

From CoreOS machine:
`curl -H "Metadata-Flavor:Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/user-data`

From your localhost (look for `- key: user-data`):
`gcloud compute instances describe --zone [zone] [machine-name]`